# Transfer function implementation

Tags: math, modelica, openmodelica

I would like to implement a transfer function into a model based component
[image: set up]

I tried to use differential equation in a model using only mathematical relationship (without using the graphical representation and the function connect()) but with no success. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78122199/how-can-i-link-connectors-with-equation), I got blocked by the compiler as my system was over-determined since I added the differential equations.

So instead of using differential equation, my new idea is to use transfer function, so:

- There will be a relationship between my input and output current (i2 = H * i1)
- There will be a relationship between my input and output voltage (v2 = H * v1)

But I have no idea how to proceed.

Thanks in advance for your help, and if you have any other suggestion or idea, feel free to share

Best regards

Comment: I suggest you look into how the MSL is implemented. Look at the Resistor, Capacitor, etc. They both extend from an interface and add the needed equation. It might work to provide your own relation between the ports (V and i) but note that the compiler adds automatically the kirchhoff's law sum to zero of currents and equality for voltages when you connect things together.

Comment: https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/blob/master/Modelica/Electrical/Analog/Interfaces/OnePort.mo

Comment: https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaStandardLibrary/blob/master/Modelica/Electrical/Analog/Basic/Resistor.mo

Comment: So what you do inside the component does not matter as long as it has the needed interface, OnePort or TwoPin.